# "Port Issue" in Deluge in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, bittorrent, deluge

Whenever I  open Deluge, I see at the bottom right corner of the screen Port Issue. I have tried switching ports and searching for help over google, but nothing helps. VPN is on if that helps.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04 LTS